# How to offset a polyline in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geometry, jts-topology-suite

I retrieve ways from OSM with Overpass API and display them in an Openlayers3 vector layer. In the case of a highway with a cycleway along it (e.g. cycleway:right=track) I want to draw a green line with a slight offset to the right of the original way, like on this raster image created with mapnik:

[image]

As there is no method in Openlayers I had a look at JSTS. Polyline buffering is coming close to what I am looking for:

```
var bufParams = new jsts.operation.buffer.BufferParameters();
bufParams.setSingleSided(true);
var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());
var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(2, bufParams);
feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered));
```

[image]

What I need is a similar function which results in just one half of the buffer polygon. Is there anyway to do this with JSTS or any other javascript library?

Comment: I found [line-offset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-offset), a npm module which makes a simple offset for a polyline. With some minor adaptations I now use it within my OL3 script. It is sufficient for my need.

Answer (score 1):

you could use https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-cut to cut the buffered polygon with the original polyline.

EDIT

jsts implements single sided buffer: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/blob/master/src/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer/BufferParameters.js#L69
Setting a negative or positive buffer value you decide which side to buffer.